# What is the name of this fantasy book?

Tags: story-identification, powers

I'm looking around the internet to find out the title of an old book (maybe 10-12 years ago) I read as a kid. I roughly remember the main story and I think the title contains the word "Super" but I can't seem to find anything about it.

The book is about the story of a group of teens/kids with superpowers that make friends with another kid that has a more special superpower than theirs.

Has anyone heard about this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This is very brief description though, and there are numerous books in the "teens with super powers" sub-genre. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details that you can recall. The more info about the book you provide, the better the odds are that someone will be able to identify it for you.

Comment: Do you remember what any of the superpowers were? For instance: Telekinesis, teleportation, telepathy, super-strength, super-speed? Any little detail might jog someone's memory.